# Any tool (online may be) to automatically fix PHP coding standards issues

Tags: php

I'm working on `WordPress plugin`, and I'm at a point to solve `php coding standards`.

I can solve standard `issues` but for me that is kind of boring and time-consuming.
There for I'm looking for any `package` that could do the same for me.

Is there any `tool` or `package`(*online or offline*) that could solve the php costandards issues for my file/s.

**For Example**:

```
if(a == 'yes'){
echo "yes"; 
}
else{
echo "no";
}
```

**Should be converted to**

```
if (a == 'yes') {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: This is a php question, not a wordpress question.

Comment: I'm working on `WordPress plugin`, that's why

Comment: There is the [WordPress Coding Standards configuration for PHP CodeSniffer](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards). I don't know if it'll do automatic fixes for you though. Some of the PHPCS IDE plugins might.